# Understanding the axiom of simplification in utility theory.

Tags: game-theory

Here is the axiom

***Simplification***

> For each $j = 1,...,J$, let $L_j$ be the following simple lottery
> $$L_j = [p_1^j(A_1),...,p_K^j(A_k)],$$
> and let $\hat{L_j}$ be the following compound lottery
> $$\hat{L_j} = [q_1(L_1),...,q_J(L_J)].$$
> For each $k = 1,2,...,K$ define
> $$r_k = q_1p_k^1 + ... + q_Jp_k^J;$$
> this is the overall probability that the outcome of the compound lottery $\hat{L}$ will be $A_k$. Consider the simple lottery
> $$L = [r_1(A_1),...,r_k(A_k)].$$
> Then
> $$\hat{L} \approx_i L$$

The equivalence relation $L_a \approx_i L_b$ means that a player $i$ is indifferent between $L_a$ and $L_b$.

I am having trouble understanding where the expression for $r_k$ comes from. Could someone help me?

Comment: Thank you for writing your question well! The quote includes the sentence "this is the overall probability that the outcome of the compound lottery $\hat{L}$ will be $A_k$". Do you understand what this sentence is asserting? If so, do you see why it's correct?

Comment: $p_k^j$ is the probability that the outcome of $L_j$ will be $A_k$. $q_j$ is the probability that the outcome of the compound lottery $\hat{L}$ is $L_j$. So $r_k = \sum_i (\text{probability that outcome of compound lottery is } L_i) \times (\text{outcome of lottery} L_i \text{ is } A_k)$

Comment: I completely agree :) but then I don't understand your question, because you seem to have just answered it!

Comment: It took some time for it to drop I think. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$p_j^k$ is the probability that the outcome of $L_j$ will be $A_k$. $q_j$ is the probability that the outcome of the compound lottery $\hat{L}$ is $L_j$. So $$r_k = \sum_i(\text{probability that outcome of compound lottery is } L_i)×(\text{outcome of lottery } L_i \text{ is } A_k) $$